# Whats a Good Video Card for Ubuntu 11.10 (unity) That supports Dual or More monitors

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, hardware-rec

Just finally decided to start working with Ubuntu as my primary OS. Went around preping all my machines and all was going well til I got to this one. Which has a NVIDIA 7300 on it, which is apparently on the Blacklist, and though there are alleged workarounds that haven't worked for me as of yet. So I have decided that I am just going to spring for a new card.

I need something that's compatible with PCI-Express and supports 64-bit, and of course supports Ubuntu 11.10/Unity. Minimal 2 monitor support the more the better but I wont complain if its only 2.

So since I'm new to Ubuntu, and far from a hardware genius what is a good Video Card for Ubuntu 11.10 (unity) That supports Dual or More monitors? Suggestions? Also I'd like to keep it in the lower budget scale ($100 or less would be nice but whatever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question has been well covered in the AskUbuntu community, where you have two good answers here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/6273/open-source-graphics-card-options

https://askubuntu.com/questions/9886/how-does-unity-work-in-multi-monitor-configurations

Although I don't have a multimonitor setup, it's true that **Ubuntu 11.04 and Ubuntu 11.10 have improved quite much the multimonitor support**, so you shouldn't have problems getting a nice dual monitor configuration out of your ATI or NVIDIA graphics card.

I prefer NVIDIA: Nouveau drivers are fine, but **their propietary drivers are really good** if you want to take advantage of 3D support. My experience with AMD/ATI GPUs hasn't been so good, although their support to Open Source drivers is fantastic. Somehow, this hasn't materialized in really good open source drivers for the moment.

Anyway, any modern card will work fine under Ubuntu for sure, **even better with propietary drivers** if you've got no problems with binary blobs.